# nagios NRPE CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds

Tags: monitor, external-monitor, monitoring, system-monitor, nagios3

Getting following error on nagios server

root@VMb:/usr/local/nagios/libexec# ./check_nrpe -H 54.255.1.99 -n
CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

On my case I had to increase the command timeout. I created my own plugin and this is my check command: `$USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_nvr -t 3600`

I run a find command that takes a longtime to execute

Comment: The check_nrpe help is confusing in this respect - it describes `-t` as a connection timeout, but it is actually also a response timeout. If it connects immediately but the check takes a long time to run, it will return a timeout message as Youssef says.

Answer (score 1):

either nrpe service is not running on that remote host or add nagios server ip on that nrpe client host configuration file

> /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
>
> "allowed_hosts=XX.XX.XX.XX"

Then restart nrpe service.

Comment: I have Install the NRPE daemon under xinetd as a service. then only restarting xinetd will do ? if yes i have done it still getting error

Comment: please check nrpe is running or not 'ps -ef|grep nrpe" should get some thing like this "/usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -d" if running then check for which port its running on default port is "5666"

Comment: @PKumar I tried running ps -ef|grep nrpe and found `nagios   30196     1  0 13:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg -f
ubuntu   30259  1623  0 13:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nrpe` I cannot see 5666 anywhere in this. can you help on this ?